# Making new polygon from other two

Tags: qgis

I use QGIS 2.18.5 and I get in stuck with two polygons I cannot solve.

The two polygons I have looks like:
[image]

What I want to get is circled with red:

[image]

What I tried/made: Cut 1 polygon and paste to other layer. Used polygon to lines toolbox then explode lines, then deleted the lines which do not needed then used the add feature to connect lines. Last I dissolve new lines then convert lines to polygons. The new polygon looks like that I wanted to get in QGIS but when I use wayline converter which convert polygons to my tractor GPS it is only shows that polygon what was originally on that layer when I started.

Look I deleted the line I do not need:

[image]

When I select Vertex Tool it appears the line I deleted earlier:

[image]

I think this is the main problem but I do not know how to remote it well..

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your drawings correctly, you would like to get a new rectangle based on one basic "green" rectangle and the closest side of another "blue" rectangle, then follow my steps:

1. extract vertices one by one for your rectangles: "Vector"->"Process Geometry"->"Extract Vertices..." and in Edit mode "Pencil" delete two points of green and blue rectangle), then copy the two remaining points of blue rectangle and paste them into temporary "Vertices" layer obtained from green rectangle, see figure 1 below

[image]

Figure 1

2. For 4 points, start geo-tool "Vector"->"Processing geometry"->"Delaunay triangulation..." see figure 2 ("you are already very close...")

[image]

Figure 2

3. Select objects (2 triangles) with "Select objects by area or by mouse click" tool and apply "Vector"->"Geoprocessing"->"Merge by feature" geo-tool to them see figure 3 below

[image]

Figure 3

See figure 4 for the result...

[image]

Figure 4

P.S. If I misunderstood your question, that's ok, maybe someone will need it :-)...

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Hello!

Thanks for your help. It is what I wanted to get but when I convert the polygon I got in QGIS to kml file and upload it to Google Earth I only see one polygons which was the original.

Comment: Did you save the result to a file with a .kml extension?

Comment: I have saved the polygons as .shp wgs84 after import it to sms advanced program where the polygon is the same what we did here in QGIS/what I wanted. After using Wayline converter which makes my file to .kml which works with my tractor. After I import .kml to Google Earth or my tractor it shows only one boundary which was the original biggest polygon. I hope you understand it

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't repeat your actions and I think you need to ask a new question describing in detail your new task...